# Help Identifying this small spider (Tennessee)

Tags: species-identification, arachnology

This small spider, about .75" when legs spread, has a distinct "teddy bear" image on its cephalothorax. Help with identity please. [image]

Comment: Welcome to Biology.SE. Please [edit] your post to include as much of the following essential information as possible to improve your chances of getting a good answer: 1) photos from multiple angles if possible; 2) the location (e.g. country and region — the more specific the better) where you observed this organism; 3) habitat information; and 4) any behavior you observed. [Detailed tag info page](https://biology.stackexchange.com/tags/species-identification/info). ——— Please also take the [tour] and then go through the [help] pages starting with [Ask] questions effectively on this site.

Answer (score 3):

This is a ground crab spider from the family *thomisidae*. The general identifiers for this family are that the front legs rotate outward (crab-like), the two hind legs are much shorter than the front two legs (about half the length), and there is a fairly distinctively wide eye arrangement, which is hard to make out in this photo.

I don't know if anyone will be able to narrow it down to genus from this pic alone... from its features and the geography, the possible genera are: Modysticus, Ozyptila, Xysticus.

You can browse some galleries of these here: https://bugguide.net/node/view/1957/bgpage